# Размер изображения

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Есть на сайте галерея фото где есть как горизотальные так и вертикальные фото

Веритикальные 808*1200

Горизонтальные 1200*808

Использую `isotope.js` чтоб уложить блоки.

Вопрос такой - как правельно вычислить высоту вертикального блока чтоб он был на уровне двух горизонтальных

Код который я использую для добавление высоты вертикальным блокам

```js
function WhP(){
   var whWpW = $('.category-pionowe').width();
     $('.category-pionowe').css("height", function () {
        Hwpt = whWpW / 0.737475;
       return Hwpt;
      });
   };
```

```css
.category{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24.69%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Но на разных мониторах немного заметно что блоки горизонтальные и вертикальные не на одном уровне

[image]

Comment: У Вас же между двумя горизонтальными картинками отступ идёт (в 2-3 пикселя, судя по картинке, без кода точно не понятно). Просто тогда `return Hwpt+2;`. Это Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Добавил код `CSS`, который влияет на даные блок. Пробивал - тоже самое